# Why do I get a "existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" exception when calling HttpClient PutAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a .Net WebApi service. I am unsuccessfully attempting to call PutAsync() on a service endpoint from a .Net client application.
When I test the same service endpoint through PostMan, it runs successfully.
What I am missing/doing wrong in my client application?

**Here is a sample block with my Web API definition:**

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Register(string useremail)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
    }
}
```

**Here is the standard boilerplate template startup code:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
    }
}
```

**The following is a code snippet for making the PutAsync() webapi call:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestUri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:44335/api/Sample/Register?useremail=jxb@tiac.net");

    var responseTask = client.PutAsync(requestUri, null);
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
}
```

When I run the above snippet, I get the following exceptions on the responseTask.Wait() call:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." "An existig
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

**I am able to run the following url through PostMan and get a successful response:**

```
https://localhost:44335/api/Sample/Register?useremail=jxb@tiac.net
```

Why is this failing with the PutAsync() method?

Comment: Postman url starts with `https` but `HttpClient` uses `http` - is this typo?

Comment: @Roman - you are the winner, that it was it. I should have had more tea while I was working late. Thx!